# Using Html Tag in Jquery Ui Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm Using Jquery Ui Dialog and have problem setting text. I'm using this code to insert a link:

```
$('#dialog').text(<a href=\"#\" >Click Here</a>).dialog();
```

But it shows the code and tags instead of the link. How can I use tags there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you use text , you exactly tell the jquery ui core to treat that string as a text.
You can simply use HTML like this :

```
$('#dialog').html('<a href="#" >Click Here</a>').dialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("<a href=\"#\" >Click Here</a>").appendTo('body').dialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're using the `text` function, which is just for text as it escapes characters needed for valid HTML.

You should instead be using the `html` function, with it your working code would be:

`$('#dialog').html("<a href=\"\">Click Here</a>").dialog();`

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ 
The place where the text appears is:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

And in the documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) there is no .text as function